# BigQuery - Inferring Datatypes of Column Values

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the best way to determine the datatype of a column value if the data has already been loaded and the data has been classified as STRING datatype (i.e. BQ table metadata has "STRING" as the datatype for every column)? I've found a few different methods, but not sure if I'm missing any or any of these is substantially more performant. The result should include statistics on the grain of each value, not just per column.

- Using a combination of CASE and SAFE_CAST on the STRING value to sum up all the instances where it successfully was able to CAST to X data type (where X is any datatype, like INT64 or DATETIME and having a few lines in query repeat the SAFE_CAST to cover all potential datatypes)
- Similar to above, but using REGEXP_CONTAINS instead of SAFE_CAST on every value and summing up all instances of TRUE (a community UDF also seems to tackle this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/blob/master/udfs/community/typeof.sql)
- (For above can also use countif(), if statements etc.)
- Loading data into a pandas dataframe and using something like pd.api.types.infer_dtype to infer automatically, but this adds overhead and more components

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a string column, then it's just that: a string. The original datatype is lost. The value may successfully cast to more than one other datatype, so what you are thinking of does not seem like a deterministic approach.

Comment: REGEX seems like a good choice - did you try?

Comment: Check out `REGEXP_CONTAINS` function and let us know how was it useful.

Comment: @GMB sure, the original datatype was lost, I guess this is just discovering within this long list of strings what "data types" (and using that term loosely now) can possibly fit, it can still help with some discovery.

Comment: @mk_sta and Felipe, the SAFE_CAST functions seems to work well enough without me having to adjust for every possible version of a date format, and without much of a performance impact. Don't have the regexes created to correctly detect every type otherwise. e.g. 40 million rows in a single column take less than a minute to perform and return whether the values can be cast to the variety of data types ending with the result I expected.

Comment: Did you observe more performance peak using `REGEXP_CONTAINS` in comparison to `SAFE_CAST` casting?

Comment: We appreciate for your research writing some valuable output in the answer for the future contributors awareness.